# What is the difference between these two list declarations?

Tags: c#, list

```
var mylist1 = new List<float>(5);
var mylist2 = new List<float>(new float[5]);
```

mylist1 gets 5 as a capacity. mylist2 gets 5 too. What is the difference between these two and which one should I use?

Comment: First one is empty, second has 5 values in it. Very easy to see by putting a breakpoint and looking inside actually

Comment: In first you set capacity, in second - items.

Comment: You could have easily seen the documentation of these two seperate constructors by either right clicking on the type and selecting "Go to Definition" or by pressing F12 while the cursor is on the type

Comment: Reading [the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs) can answer all your questions, easily.

Comment: @OguzOzgul, thats the metadata, to get to the documentation it is F1 while the constructor has the blinking cursor in it.

Comment: For those voting to close the question: I think the question itself is abolutely clear and valid. However It´s a bad question as it shows not much research-afford.

Comment: @scott-chamberlain F12 and you will get to the constructor in the meta data and you will see the /// comments of the constructors and that should be sufficient. I did this for List<T> and it tells me much. I alwyas F12 first and then F1 if I need anything more. Of course F1 is the real one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first declaration creates a list with an underlying array with a size of 5.

The second declaration copies data from the passed array to the underlying array in the list.

So the second declaration needs to:

- Create an empty array
- Copy the values in that array to another array

Since it's also harder to read (what's the point of passing an empty array to a list constructor?), there really isn't any reason at all to use the second *instead* of the first.

The reason the overload is there is to allow you to *prefill* the list with values from another array or enumerable. For example:

```
var list = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 100));
```

(though of course, even then you'd usually use `Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList()` instead :))

Comment: In addition to post: the first list has its `Count` property equal to 0 while the second one has equal to 5.

Comment: @Luaan thx for the answer but what is the point of declaring the capacity beforehand when dealing with dynamic arrays? What is the point if I declared capacity 500 instead of 5? I mean there is nothing created like mylist2 array values in mylist1. I dont understand this capacity thing when dealing with dynamic arrays in C#.

Comment: @Lyrk Better performance if you know the amount of objects beforehand. Less reallocations of arrays. However, it is obsolete when having such little numbers, like 5 in your example.

Comment: There is no real dynamic array. The list just simulates one.

Comment: @Lyrk Well, you need to understand how `List` works - it uses a single internal array to hold all its items. So it starts with, say, 20 items in an array. When you try to add 21th item, it needs to expand that array - but that means creating a whole new array, and copying the old one over. If you're adding 500 items, that means you'll do a lot of reallocations and copying, which can be a significant performance penalty. If you know in advance that you'll have around 500 items, using that capacity is a simple option to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

The first create a List having capacity 5, but empty.i.e, if you access myList1[3] you get an error.
The second create a List of float containing already 5 elements. each element will have value 0.0, i.e the default value for a float